# Changing column names of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I have a data frame called "newprice" (see below) and I want to change the column names in my program in R.

```
> newprice
   Chang.  Chang.   Chang.
1     100       36      136
2     120      -33       87
3     150       14      164
```

In fact this is what am doing:

```
names(newprice)[1]<-paste("premium")
names(newprice)[2]<-paste("change")
names(newprice)[3]<-paste("newprice")
```

I have not put this in a loop because I want each column name to be different as you see.

When I paste my program into R console this is the output it gives me:

```
> names(newprice)[1]<-paste(“premium”)
Error: unexpected input in "names(newprice)[1]<-paste(“"
> names(newprice)[2]<-paste(“change”)
Error: unexpected input in "names(newprice)[2]<-paste(“"
> names(newprice)[3]<-paste(“newpremium”)
Error: unexpected input in "names(newprice)[3]<-paste(“"
```

I have equally tried using the `c()` function-for example `c("premium")`, instead of the `paste()` function, but to no avail.

Could someone help me to figure this out?

Comment: If Dirk's answer works then the problem was that you were working with a matrix rather than with a dataframe. You can check this with either `is.matrix` or `str`.

Comment: See this answer on dplyr::rename http://stackoverflow.com/a/26146202/1831980

Comment: `colnames(newprice)<- c("premium","change","newprice")`

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with the quality of your code. You're just using the wrong symbol. This “ is not recognized by R, use " instead. I know they may look the same. Look close: “ ". That's it.

Comment: Several answers below using a hard-coded position, for instance, `2` in `colnames(X)[2]`. This is usually a not good practice because it is sensitive to data change. What if you add another column before this specific column to your data? Instead, try something like the answer provided by **Hagos**.

Answer (score 692):

Use the `colnames()` function:

```
R> X <- data.frame(bad=1:3, worse=rnorm(3))
R> X
  bad     worse
1   1 -2.440467
2   2  1.320113
3   3 -0.306639
R> colnames(X) <- c("good", "better")
R> X
  good    better
1    1 -2.440467
2    2  1.320113
3    3 -0.306639
```

You can also subset:

```
R> colnames(X)[2] <- "superduper"
```

Comment: @Dirk Why not using names() instead of colnames()?

Comment: Great! You can also subset multiple columns at once (useful on big data frames). `colnames(X)[c(1,2)] <- c("good", "better")`

Comment: Try `setnames()` in the `data.table` package. Use something like `setnames(DT,"b","B")` or `setnames(DT,c("a","E"),c("A","F"))`

Comment: Weirdly, after setting the column names of the data frame `q1`, trying to mutate the data frame using `dplyr` as in `q1 <- q1 %>% mutate(rel_count = count / 482462)` results in the error `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : unknown column 'days'` (where `days` is a new name given to the column). This is really frustrating.

Answer (score 235):

I use this:

```
colnames(dataframe)[which(names(dataframe) == "columnName")] <- "newColumnName"
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is somehow annoying with R: Why is it so difficult to change the column name if you do not want to use the index number but the old name :(

Comment: This method has the advantage that you do not have to worry about the position of the column, as long as you know its original name. I think this is the preferred method as you may - later - make changes to the code that change the position of the column you want to rename.

Comment: Can also use `data.table::setnames(dataframe,'Old','New')`

Answer (score 90):

The error is caused by the "smart-quotes" (or whatever they're called).  The lesson here is, "don't write your code in an 'editor' that converts quotes to smart-quotes".

```
names(newprice)[1]<-paste(“premium”)  # error
names(newprice)[1]<-paste("premium")  # works
```

Also, you don't need `paste("premium")` (the call to `paste` is redundant) and it's a good idea to put spaces around `<-` to avoid confusion (e.g. `x <- -10; if(x<-3) "hi" else "bye"; x`).

Answer (score 76):

Try:

```
names(newprice)[1] <- "premium"
```

Answer (score 55):

The new recommended way to do this is to use the `setNames` function.  See 
`?setNames`.  Since this creates a new copy of the `data.frame`, be sure to assign the result to the original `data.frame`, if that is your intention.

```
data_frame <- setNames(data_frame, c("premium","change","newprice"))
```

Newer versions of R will give you warning if you use `colnames` in some of the ways suggested by earlier answers.

If this were a `data.table` instead, you could use the `data.table` function `setnames`, which can modify specific column names or a single column name *by reference*:

```
setnames(data_table, "old-name", "new-name")
```

Answer (score 55):

I had the same issue and this piece of code worked out for me.

```
names(data)[names(data) == "oldVariableName"] <- "newVariableName"
```

In short, this code does the following:

`names(data)` looks into all the names in the dataframe (`data`)

`[names(data) == oldVariableName]` extracts the variable name (`oldVariableName`) you want to get renamed and `<- "newVariableName"` assigns the new variable name.

Comment: how would this work if you had a vector with e.g. 3 oldVariableNames?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for -> 2 thumbs up !!

Comment: Nice, not index hard-coded.

Answer (score 28):

Similar to the others:

```
cols <- c("premium","change","newprice")
colnames(dataframe) <- cols
```

Quite simple and easy to modify.

Answer (score 23):

Use this to change column name by colname function.

```
colnames(newprice)[1] = "premium"
colnames(newprice)[2] = "change"
colnames(newprice)[3] = "newprice"
```

Answer (score 13):

If you need to rename not all but multiple column at once when you only know the old column names you can use `colnames` function and `%in%` operator. Example:

```
df = data.frame(bad=1:3, worse=rnorm(3), worst=LETTERS[1:3])

   bad      worse    worst
1   1 -0.77915455       A
2   2  0.06717385       B
3   3 -0.02827242       C
```

Now you want to change "bad" and "worst" to "good" and "best". You can use

```
colnames(df)[which(colnames(df) %in% c("bad","worst") )] <- c("good","best")
```

This results in

```
  good      worse  best
1    1 -0.6010363    A
2    2  0.7336155    B
3    3  0.9435469    C
```

Comment: That code assumes the ordering of your column names equal the ordering of the inserts

Answer (score 13):

My column names is as below

```
colnames(t)
[1] "Class"    "Sex"      "Age"      "Survived" "Freq"
```

I want to change column name of Class and Sex

```
colnames(t)=c("STD","Gender","AGE","SURVIVED","FREQ")
```

Answer (score 13):

There are a couple options with `dplyr::rename()` and `dplyr::select()`:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column('car_model') %>%                            # convert rowname to a column. tibble must be installed.
  select(car_model, est_mpg = mpg, horse_power = hp, everything()) %>%   # rename specific columns and reorder
  rename(weight = wt, cylinders = cyl) %>%                               # another option for renaming specific columns that keeps everything by default
  head(2)
      car_model est_mpg horse_power cylinders disp drat weight  qsec vs am gear carb
1     Mazda RX4      21         110         6  160  3.9  2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2 Mazda RX4 Wag      21         110         6  160  3.9  2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

There are also three scoped variants of `dplyr::rename()`: `dplyr::rename_all()` for all column names, `dplyr::rename_if()` for conditionally targeting column names, and `dplyr::rename_at()` for select named columns. The following example replaces spaces and periods with an underscore and converts everything to lower case:

```
iris %>%  
  rename_all(~gsub("\\s+|\\.", "_", .)) %>% 
  rename_all(tolower) %>% 
  head(2)
  sepal_length sepal_width petal_length petal_width species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

`dplyr::select_all()` can also be used in a similar way:

```
iris %>%  
  select_all(~gsub("\\s+|\\.", "_", .)) %>% 
  select_all(tolower) %>% 
  head(2)
  sepal_length sepal_width petal_length petal_width species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: See dplyr::rename_with() for updated tidyverse approaches as well.

Answer (score 10):

try:

```
names(newprice) <- c("premium", "change", "newprice")
```

Answer (score 10):

Just to correct and slightly extend Scott Wilson answer.
You can use data.table's `setnames` function on data.frames too.

Do not expect speed up of the operation but you can expect the `setnames` to be more efficient for memory consumption as it updates column names by reference. This can be tracked with `address` function, see below.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
n = 1e8

df = data.frame(bad=sample(1:3, n, TRUE), worse=rnorm(n))
address(df)
#[1] "0x208f9f00"
colnames(df) <- c("good", "better")
address(df)
#[1] "0x208fa1d8"
rm(df)

dt = data.table(bad=sample(1:3, n, TRUE), worse=rnorm(n))
address(dt)
#[1] "0x535c830"
setnames(dt, c("good", "better"))
address(dt)
#[1] "0x535c830"
rm(dt)
```

So if you are hitting your memory limits you may consider to use this one instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can just do the editing by:

```
newprice <- edit(newprice)
```

and change the column name manually.

Comment: Doesn't this work only for vector and factor elements? `> locanatmodelset<-edit(locanatmodelset)
Error in edit.data.frame(locanatmodelset) : 
  can only handle vector and factor elements`

Comment: It works for data frames at least. That's what I know.

Answer (score 3):

This may be helpful:

```
rename.columns=function(df,changelist){
  #renames columns of a dataframe
  for(i in 1:length(names(df))){
    if(length(changelist[[names(df)[i]]])>0){
      names(df)[i]= changelist[[names(df)[i]]]
    }
  }
  df
}

# Specify new dataframe
df=rename.columns(df,list(old.column='new.column.name'))
```

Answer (score 2):

In case we have 2 dataframes the following works

```
 DF1<-data.frame('a', 'b')
 DF2<-data.frame('c','d')
```

We change names of DF1 as follows

```
 colnames(DF1)<- colnames(DF2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change data frame column name

```
colnames(dataset)[colnames(dataset) == 'name'] <- 'newcolumnname'
```

Answer (score 1):

One option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dataframe)

setnames(dataframe,'Old1','New1')
setnames(dataframe,'Old2','New2')
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
newprice<- setNames(newprice, c("premium", "change", "newprice"))
```