# How to deal with nonstandard column names (white space, punctuation, starts with numbers)

Tags: r, dplyr, r-faq

```
df <- structure(list(`a a` = 1:3, `a b` = 2:4), .Names = c("a a", "a b"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

and the data looks like

```
  a a a b
1   1   2
2   2   3
3   3   4
```

Following call to select

```
select(df, 'a a')
```

gives

```
Error in abs(ind[ind < 0]) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

How can I select "a a" and/or rename it to something without space using `select`? I know the following approaches:

1. `names(df)[1] <- "a"`
2. `select(df, a=1)`
3. `select(df, ends_with("a"))`

but if I am working on a large data set, how can I get an exact match without knowing the index numer or similar column names?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You may `select` the variable by using backticks `` ` ``.

```
select(df, `a a`)
#   a a
# 1   1
# 2   2
# 3   3
```

However, if your main objective is to rename the column, you may use `rename` in `plyr` package, in which you can use both `""` and ``` `` ```.

```
rename(df, replace = c("a a" = "a"))
rename(df, replace = c(`a a` = "a"))
```

Or in `base` R:

```
names(df)[names(df) == "a a"] <- "a"
```

For a more thorough description on the use of various quotes, see `?Quotes`. The 'Names and Identifiers' section is especially relevant here:

> other [syntactically invalid] names can be used provided they are quoted. The preferred quote is the backtick".

See also `?make.names` about valid names.

See also [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502465/replacement-for-rename-in-dplyr) about renaming in `dplyr`

Comment: you can also do the same with `select`: `select(df, a=\`a a\`)`

Comment: @Arun, Thanks for your suggestion. But doesn't this both rename "a a", _and_ select this variable only (in contrast to `rename`)?

Comment: Henrik, you're right. But `rename` will copy the entire data.frame just to rename the columns. So, I'd not use it / consider it efficient. I'm not sure if there's a way like `setattr` in `data.table`. Ex: `setattr(df, 'names', c("a", "b"))` renames here by reference.

Answer (score 4):

Some alternatives to backticks, good as of dplyr 0.5.0, the current version as of this writing.

If you're trying to programmatically select an argument as a column and you don't want to rename or do something like `paste`/`sprintf` the column name into backticks, you can use `as.name` in conjunction with the [non-standard evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) version of `select`, which is `select_`:

```
dplyr::select_(df, as.name("a a"))
```

Many of the `dplyr` functions have non-standard versions. In the case of `select` specifically, you can also use the standard version in conjunction with the select helper `one_of`. See `?dplyr::select_helpers` for documentation:

```
dplyr::select(df, dplyr::one_of("a a"))
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Even dplyr's NSE version doesn't handle it. For example:
    `colnames(mtcars)[1] <- "Miles Per Gallon"`
    `mtcars %>% select_("Miles Per Gallon")`
This will return an error.

Comment: `mtcars %>% select_(as.name("Miles Per Gallon"))` works.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, the code which previously gave the error now runs:

```
> select(df, 'a a')
  a a
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

So a legitimate answer to the question 'How to deal with nonstandard column names?' is now, write them as strings (for select this works out of the box, but for mutate, you need to use something like `mutate(df, a = .data[['a a']])`