# Select name with special characters in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I de-select a column named "(Intercept)" using dplyr::select and not using the column-index?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

tib<-tribble(~"(Intercept)",~b,
              80,3,
              80,4,
              80,4)

tib[,-1] # works

select(tib,eval(parse(("-(Intercept)")))) # does not work
select(tib,as.name(("-(Intercept)"))) # does not work 
select(tib,-"\(Intercept\)") # does not work
```

Thanks&kind regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842232/dplyr-select-column-names-containing-white-space?rq=1

Comment: Minus only works for numeric position seeking. If you have a name, you first have to map its position first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to use backquotes

```
tib %>% 
    select(-`(Intercept)`)
tib %>% 
    select(`(Intercept)`)
```