# How can I fix this invalid type error using lm()?

Tags: r, error-handling, dataset, linear-regression, lm

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = data$conservationstatus ~ data$latitude,  : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'data$conservationstatus
```

I have a dataset (called data, after reading a CSV file), and it has the columns Conservation Status and Latitude. I'm trying to perform linear regression on these two using

```
lm(data$ConservationStatus ~ data$Latitude, data = data)
```

However, I keep getting the error above. It seems like it's because my column has two words in in it. I've tried data$Conservation Status, data$'Conservation Status', data$Conservation.Status, but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: I suspect you're using the `tidyverse` `read_csv()` function to import your data (base R's `read.csv()` would have changed the variable name to `Conservation.Status`.  It might be a good idea to learn to use the `rename()` function to convert your variable names to R-friendlier (no spaces) values before running `lm` ...

Comment: Related/duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842232/dplyr-select-column-names-containing-white-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the formula without `data$`.  If the column name have spaces, use backquotes to wrap the column name

```
model <- lm(`Conservation Status` ~ Latitude, data = data)
```

It can be reproduced with a simple example

```
data(iris)
lm(iris$epal.Length ~ iris$Species, iris)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = iris$epal.Length ~ iris$Species,
> :    invalid type (NULL) for variable 'iris$epal.Length'

and using the correct syntax

```
lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris)

#Call:
#lm(formula = Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)

#Coefficients:
#      (Intercept)  Speciesversicolor   Speciesvirginica  
#            5.006              0.930              1.582
```

Answer (score 2):

You are likely mis-spelling a variable name, check `colnames(data)` to see how it is spelled.

For instance,

```r
lm(mtcars$MPG ~ mtcars$disp)
# Error in model.frame.default(formula = mtcars$MPG ~ mtcars$disp, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
#   invalid type (NULL) for variable 'mtcars$MPG'

lm(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$disp)
# Call:
# lm(formula = mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$disp)
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)  mtcars$disp  
#    29.59985     -0.04122
```

Noting that `mpg` is lower-case, not UPPER case as I tried the first time.

```r
colnames(mtcars)
#  [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

I agree with @akrun's suggestion to instead use `lm(mpg ~ disp, data=data)`, as the nomenclature (to me) seems more readable, but it will throw a different error in that case, as you found out.