# Unable to specify column names with space

Tags: r, tidyverse, mutate

Although this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842232/how-to-deal-with-nonstandard-column-names-white-space-punctuation-starts-with) showed that one could use backtick `` ` `` to select columns that had space in their names, I couldn't do that in the following code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)

df <- colon[colon$etype==2, c("time", "age")]
num_summary <- do.call(cbind, lapply(df, summary)) %>% 
  t() %>% mutate(Interquatrile = `3rd Qu.` - `1st Qu.`)
```

Which would result in the following error

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"
```

Could you please explain what I did wrong and how to solve the problem without renaming the column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer this has nothing to do with your column names and everything to do with the fact that `cbind` (as well as `t`) by default creates a *matrix*, not a data.frame.

To create a table you don’t need to go the detour via a matrix (and `as_tibble`) at all — instead, use `bind_cols` or, in your case (omitting the `t()`), `bind_rows`:

```
num_summary <- lapply(df, summary) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(Interquartile = `3rd Qu.` - `1st Qu.`)
```

The code above preserves the class and attributes of the summary table. This isn’t harmful, but if you want to get rid of extraneous attributes and just want to retain the bare numeric values, you can apply `as.vector` (or `c`) to all columns to achieve that:

```
num_summary <- lapply(df, summary) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.vector)) %>%
  mutate(Interquartile = `3rd Qu.` - `1st Qu.`)
```

Comment: Awesome solutions. Could you please explain why we need `mutate(across(everything(), c))` before `mutate(Interquartile`? Also what did `c` in `mutate(across(everything(), c))` mean? Thanks.

Comment: @Nemo LIke I said, we don't *need* it but if you wrap an object in a `c()` call, [it drops all attributes](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html#:~:text=c%20is%20sometimes%20used%20for%20its%20side%20effect%20of%20removing%20attributes%20except%20names), so the columns become raw `numeric`s instead of summary table types. Actually using `as.vector` would have been more explicit, I'll amend the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with your columns but with your general data structure:

Use instead `as_tibble()` to transform a matrix to a tibble (dataframe) such that you can use the `mutate` function:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(df, summary)) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Interquatrile = `3rd Qu.` - `1st Qu.`)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
   Min. `1st Qu.` Median   Mean `3rd Qu.`  Max. Interquatrile
  <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>
1    23       806   1976 1670.       2364  3329          1558
2    18        53     61   59.8        69    85            16
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `mutate` with a `matrix`, but `mutate` needs a `data.frame`.

Maybe you use `rbind` instead of `cbind` and `t` and convert the `matrix` to a `data.frame`, that `mutate` can work with it.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(df, summary)) %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% mutate(Interquatrile = `3rd Qu.` - `1st Qu.`)
#     Min. 1st Qu. Median       Mean 3rd Qu. Max. Interquatrile
#time   23     806   1976 1669.95587    2364 3329          1558
#age    18      53     61   59.75457      69   85            16
```

Or your code by using in addition `as.data.frame`.

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(df, summary)) %>% 
  t() %>% as.data.frame %>% mutate(Interquatrile = `3rd Qu.` - `1st Qu.`)
#     Min. 1st Qu. Median       Mean 3rd Qu. Max. Interquatrile
#time   23     806   1976 1669.95587    2364 3329          1558
#age    18      53     61   59.75457      69   85            16
```

Or skip the conversion to `data.frame` and `cbind` *Interquatrile* to the matrix.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(df, summary)) %>%
  cbind(., Interquatrile = .[,"3rd Qu."] - .[,"1st Qu."])
#     Min. 1st Qu. Median       Mean 3rd Qu. Max. Interquatrile
#time   23     806   1976 1669.95587    2364 3329          1558
#age    18      53     61   59.75457      69   85            16
```

Or do it directly in the function called by `lapply` and get also a `matrix`, which could be converted to a `data.frame` if needed.

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(df, function(x) {
          y <- summary(x)
          c(y, Interquatrile = y[["3rd Qu."]] - y[["1st Qu."]])} ))
#     Min. 1st Qu. Median       Mean 3rd Qu. Max. Interquatrile
#time   23     806   1976 1669.95587    2364 3329          1558
#age    18      53     61   59.75457      69   85            16
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. Could you please explain what `\(x)` and `;` in the part `y <- summary(x);`?

Comment: `\(x)` is a short notation of `function(x)` and `;` was needed when I wrote this in one line. I have cleaned this now.

Comment: It's difficult to decide yours or @Konrard Rudolph's solution as the accepted answer. I went for his as it's easier to understand. Thank you!