# dplyr rename command with spaces

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I have tried multiple variations of the `rename` function in `dplyr`.

I have a data frame called `alldata`, and a column within the data frame named `WindDirection:N`. I am trying to rename it to `Wind Direction`.  I understand creating variable names containing spaces is not a good practice, but I want it to be named as such to improve readability for a selectInput list in shiny, and even if I try to rename it to `WindDirection` I get the same error messages.

I have tried:

```
rename(alldata, Wind Direction = WindDirection:N)
```

which gives the error message:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "rename(alldata, Wind Direction"

```
rename(alldata, `Wind Direction` = `WindDirection:N`)
```

which does not give an error message, but also does not rename the variable

```
rename(alldata, "Wind Direction" = "WindDirection:N")
```

which gives the error message:

> Error: Arguments to rename must be unquoted variable names. Arguments Wind Direction are not.

I then tried the same 3 combinations swapping the variable names, that is, putting the old variable first and the new variable second, obtaining similar error messages.

I then tried to specify the package as below and tried all 6 combinations again.

```
dplyr::rename(alldata, `Wind Direction` = `WindDirection:N`)
```

obtaining similar error messages as the first time.

I have used [the following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502465/replacement-for-rename-in-dplyr) as a reference.

Comment: Use backticks. `rename(\`Wind Direction\` = WindDirection)`

Comment: @eipi10 I have tried that, the code displays the entire data frame in the console, but does not rename the variable.

Comment: well, it is because you have to assign the new data.frame `alldata <- rename(alldata,...` that's how dplyr works

Comment: `names(alldata)[names(alldata)=="Wind Direction"] <- "WindDirection"`

Comment: Thank you @agenis that worked

Comment: Just to expand on @eipi10 comment, see `?Quotes`: "Such identifiers are also known as syntactic names and may be used directly in R code. Almost always, other names can be used provided they are quoted. The preferred quote is the backtick (‘⁠`⁠’), and deparse will normally use it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as agenis pointed out, my mistake was not redefining the dataframe after renaming the variable.

So where I had

```
dplyr::rename(alldata, `Wind Direction` = `WindDirection:N`)
```

I should have

```
alldata <- dplyr::rename(alldata, `Wind Direction` = `WindDirection:N`)
```

Comment: this is not correct usage for names with spaces