# aggregate prints incorrect number of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I used the aggregate function to get the range by factor level. I am trying to rename the columns, but the output from the aggregate function does not have the min and max as separate columns.

```
# example data
size_cor <- data.frame(SpCode = rep(c(200, 400, 401), 3),
                       Length = c(45, 23, 56, 89, 52, 85, 56, 45, 78))

# aggregate function
spcode_range <- with(size_cor, aggregate(Length, list(SpCode), FUN = range))
```

Output:

```
spcode_range 

  Group.1 x.1 x.2
1     200  45  89
2     400  23  52
3     401  56  85
```

Data structure:

```
str(spcode_range)

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Group.1: num  200 400 401
 $ x      : num [1:3, 1:2] 45 23 56 89 52 85

dim(spcode_range)
[1] 3 2
```

The output has three columns: `Group.1`, `x.1` (min) and `x.2` (max), but the dataframe has only 2 columns.  I have tried setNames, rename and name with no success because I am trying to name three columns when R has only 2 columns.

Comment: You can use: `names(spcode_range) <- c("group","min","max")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing column names of a data frame in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081439/changing-column-names-of-a-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: I can't use names.  Here is the error message R gives when names is called:Error in names(spcode_range) <- c("group", "min", "max") : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]

Comment: Sorry I hit enter too fast.  The dataframe that comes out of the aggregate function has only 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what happened here is that you've called the `range` function by group which returned two values at a time. The `aggregate` function returned a `data.frame` (which it always does unless the data set is a `ts` class) with those values as a `matrix` in a single column (of class `matrix` obviously).

Then, when you `print` it, it triggers the `print.data.frame` method which in turn calls `format.data.frame` which converts each column in the matrix column into a separate column (see `str(format.data.frame(spcode_range))`) and then, the printed result is actually not the actual `data.frame` you are trying to print (don't ask me why, probably for convenience - as it is not clear how to print a `matrix` within a `data.frame`).

So basically, one way to fix this is to combine `do.call` and `cbind.data.frame`, e.g.

```
res <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, aggregate(Length ~ SpCode, size_cor, range))
str(res)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ SpCode  : num  200 400 401
# $ Length.1: num  45 23 56
# $ Length.2: num  89 52 85
```

Or just use other packages such `dplyr` or `data.table` which were designed to (among other stuff) replace/improve data manipulation operations in R.