# Using dplyr functions on variables named "."

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Sometimes when generating a data frame from a list, the variable is named "." by default. How can I refer to this variable within dplyr functions, if only to change the variable name to something more appropriate.

```
# Code that produces my data frame with "." as column name
library(tidyverse)

d <- data.frame(`.` = 1, row.names = "a") 

# Now my code fails because `.` is a poor column name for dplyr functions:
d %>% select(model = rownames(.), outlier = `.`)
```

Comment: change the variable name...

Comment: If you're open to changing the column names as B Williams suggested above, this post includes various approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081439/changing-column-names-of-a-data-frame

Comment: `.` will cause more problems than just with dplyr. Change the variable name.

Comment: Hello @HongOoi, I agree, this is just a reprex. The output from another function is naming the column ".".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't actually a problem with the column named . its a problem with referencing the rownames in select() see

```
d <- data.frame(test = 1, row.names = "a")
d %>% select(model = rownames(.), outlier = test)
```

still returns `Error: Strings must match column names. Unknown columns: a`

just use

```
d <- data.frame(`.` = 1, row.names = "a") 
d %>% select(outlier = '.')
```

will rename the column to outlier

Answer (score 0):

**Given**

```
d <- data.frame(`.` = 1, row.names = "a")
```

**Base R Solution**

```
colnames(d) <- 'newname'
```

**Dplyr Solution**

```
d %>% rename(newname = '.')
```

Comment: With the dplyr solution, you can rename and pipe onwards!

Comment: `setNames`/`purrr::set_names` pipes nicely

Comment: When I use your dplyr solution I get "Error in captureDots(strict = `__quosured`) : the argument has already been evaluated"

Comment: @Joe, you're right. I forgot to include quote marks, so I updated the answer. That dplyr solution should work now. Try it out. :)