# Change column name in matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I simply want to change the name of the column in the matrix from "worldwide_vector" to "Worldwide". Everything is in the image.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing column names of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081439/changing-column-names-of-a-data-frame)

Comment: Just from your last two questions, you may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a matrix, you need `colnames`

```
colnames(star_wars_matrix)[colnames(star_wars_matrix) == "worldwide_vector"] <- "Worldwide"
```

Comment: Why do I get -1 for this?