# How to rbind diff data frame with diff headers

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have diff data frames

data frame A

| bed | bake | sea | tea |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa | 232 | charles | 232 |
| bb | 456 | james | 456 |
| bbb | 456 | becky | 456 |
| ccaa | 456 | brown | 456 |

Data frame B

| BEARD | bay | pass | butter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| james | 232 | 232 | bb |
| brat | 456 | 456 | ccaa |
| Joyce | 456 | 456 | aabb |
| Mayer | 456 | 456 | dd |

I have many of data frame A and data frame B in a folder
what command should I run to re-arrange them base on data frame A header and row bind them as one

basically what I want the column to re-arrange themselves using the data frame A header as the base

I want to have something like this

| bed | bake | sea | tea |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa | 232 | charles | 232 |
| bb | 456 | james | 456 |
| bbb | 456 | becky | 456 |
| ccaa | 456 | brown | 456 |
| bb | 232 | james | 232 |
| ccaa | 456 | brat | 456 |
| aabb | 456 | Joyce | 456 |
| dd | 456 | Mayer | 456 |

Comment: change the colnames in Data frame B so they match where you want to join them on Data frame A, then use something like `data.table::rbindlist(..., use.names = TRUE)` for tyhe rowbinding

Comment: can you just change the column names of dataframe B?

Comment: I have many type of data frame B in a folder
how do I change the name for each

Comment: Have you had a look at related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081439/changing-column-names-of-a-data-frame, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402371/combine-two-data-frames-by-rows-rbind-when-they-have-different-sets-of-columns

Comment: it doesnt answer my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `merge` and `by` you will have to match up the columns though

df1:

```
df1<-read.table (text="bed  bake    sea tea
aa  232 charles 232
bb  456 james   456
bbb 456 becky   456
ccaa    456 brown   456", header=TRUE)
```

df2:

```
df2<-read.table (text="BEARD    bay pass    butter
james   232 232 bb
brat    456 456 ccaa
Joyce   456 456 aabb
Mayer   456 456 dd", header=TRUE)
```

merge data:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x=c("bed", "bake", "sea", "tea"), 
             by.y=c("butter", "bay", "BEARD", "pass"),all = TRUE)
```

If all your data frame A's and all your data frame B's have the same column order, you can rearrange dataframe B's columns using the follow. NOTE: it is unclear what order `bay` and `pass`should be in because they contain the same data.

```
dfB <- dfB[c(4,2,1,3)]
```

After you rearrange You can change the column names of data frame B using the following

```
colnames(dfB) <- c("bed", "baked","sea","tea")
```

and then just do a simple `rbind()` after

```
dfAB <- rbind(dfA,dfB)
```

Comment: what of if I have this data in a folder with  diff data frames but the headers are different like the sample I gave, for example we have many of Data frame A and many of Data frame B in a folder and I'm trying to arrange them base on data frame A and row bind all

Comment: @user16087142 You have to have some kind of knowledge of the structure of your data frames. If all of data frame B's are randomly ordered columns then there isn't much you can do

Comment: what im saying is that i have many of Data frame A in a folder with the same structure
and I also have many of Data frame B in a folder with the same data frame B structure
I'm looking for how to restructure them to align Data frame A structure

Comment: You can just rearrange the columns before hand using `dfB <- dfB[c(4,2,1,3)]`, change the columns names of dfB using `colnames(dfB) <- c("bed", "baked","sea","tea")`, and then just rbind the two with `dfAB <- rbind(dfA,dfB)`

Comment: @user16087142 just updated my question for you

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but case when all data frame names differ and you don't wanna keep open the data frame one by one to see which one is align with data frame A or which does not.
I'm saying is there no script like Case_when any of the data frame did not match the data frame A, then rearrange to suit that frame Based on defined parameters 
I'm just saying or thinking 
thanks for the ideas and contribution so far