# Can't Change Column Names with $

Tags: r

I've checked the other questions related to this issue but none of the solutions worked ([Changing column names of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081439/changing-column-names-of-a-data-frame), [Renaming column names in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346283/renaming-column-names-in-pandas))

I have a data frame where I use indexes to merge data frames together. That works fine, except the new column headers on the data frame likes to double the name in the new column. For example: I expect the new column in the main data frame to say "LiveDemand" but instead it says "LiveDemand$LiveDemand".

I then try to use colnames() to replace the column header to a new name. I get no errors, but when I check the data frame the name is unchanged. Can anyone help explain why? Here is my code:

```
mainDF$LiveDemand <- DemandDF[DemandIndexes, "LiveDemand"]
#Result is a new column called 'LiveDemand$LiveDemand'
colnames(mainDF)[which(names(mainDF) == "LiveDemand$LiveDemand")] <- "LiveDemand"
#I've also tried
colnames(mainDF)[18] <- "LiveDemand"
#This as well
mainDF<- rename(mainDF, LiveDemand= "LiveDemand")
```

All three methods give no errors, but the column header doesn't change (none of them do). What is really strange is when I use rename, if I say the old column name is "LiveDemand$LiveDemand" it gives me an error saying it doesn't exist, but when I go to view the data frame, it clearly says "LiveDemand$LiveDemand".
Any ideas?

Comment: CAn you do `mainDF$LiveDemand <- DemandDF$LiveDemand[DemandIndexes]`  I am assuming that either your dataset is tibble or data.table.

Comment: Making this reproducible would be good, could you share `dput(mainDF[1:3, ])`?

Comment: try surrounding the name that inlcudes `$` with back ticks:  `\`LiveDemand$LiveDemand\`` instead of quotation marks `"LiveDemand$LiveDemand"`

Comment: Thank you Akrun! That worked around the columns from even appearing with a doubling name. I still find it odd that I couldn't replace their names like normal column names could be; however, now it's a non-issue so that works too!

Comment: @Steven It depens on the class of your data.  If it is a data.frame, then `DemandDF[DemandIndexes, "LiveDemand"]` would coerce to a vector as drop = TRUE is by default with `[`, whereas in tibble or data.table, it still returns a tibble/data.table with a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be better to directly extract the column as vector with `$` and then subset using the index, thus avoiding the `drop` argument value (which is `TRUE` - for data.frame and `FALSE` for data.table/tibble - i.e. it coerce to a vector when there is a single row or single column in data.frame, whereas in tibble, data.table, it will still be a tibble/data.table with a single column)

```
mainDF$LiveDemand <- DemandDF$LiveDemand[DemandIndexes]
```